# (PART 2) what does this fluid error mean? No unique path segment could be found after 100 iterations

Tags: fluid, typo3-flow

This is a continuation of a previously asked and answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068612/what-does-this-fluid-error-means-no-unique-path-segment-could-be-found-after-10) that has cropped up again and needs a different solution ( different problem but same error message  ).

Again the links to the shippingAddress action are not rendering:

```
 <f:link.action action="shippingAddress" controller="Order" arguments="{address: shippingAddress, changeAddress: 1}"><f:translate id="seethroughweb.shop.change-address">Change</f:translate></f:link.action>
```

When debugging and expecting to find that the address variable is NULL but I found it was not, however it was being reported as the wrong type by var_dump - it was shown to be:     `TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\Proxies\__CG__\SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\Address persistable proxy`

but should be:

```
SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\Address prototype persistable proxy
```

So the question now is - why is the wrong type reported?  Why is the variable the wrong type?   Looking at the code everything seems to refer to  `@param \SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\Address $address`

The resulting exception in the Exception Logs is as before:

```
Uncaught exception #1316441798: No unique path segment could be found after 100 iterations.

80 TYPO3\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Link\ActionViewHelper_Original::render("shippingAddress", array|2|, "Order", NULL, NULL, "", "", array|0|, FALSE, array|0|, FALSE)
79 call_user_func_array(array|2|, array|11|)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing do do with the type of the class. `TYPO3 Flow` creates proxy classes for each class. That means it generates new code and a new class for each of your classes.

The error is about a loop in the detection algorithm for the template. You somehow managed to trick Flow into going into an endless loop here.

Comment: Maybe but I have no idea how or when, I also found another page with the same error when trying to render  link to an action which also involves passing an address object.

Answer (score 0):

as Philipp already stated, these two issues are probably not related (in this case it's [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) though that creates the proxy, not Flow).

If you search for the exception code **1316441798**, you can see that this exception is thrown in the `IdentityRoutePart`.
Probably you have a route like the following:

```
-
  uriPattern: 'some/path/{address}'
  defaults:
    '@package':     'SeeThroughWeb.Shop'
    '@controller':  'Order'
    '@action':      'shippingAddress'
  routeParts:
    'address':
      objectType: 'SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\Address'
```

With the `objectType` option you tell Flow to use a database table to map "{address}" to an instance of `SeeThroughWeb\Shop\Domain\Model\Address`. This is done in order to keep the URL valid even if the entity changes.

If two entities resolve to the same URL segment, Flow will append a counter (e.g. "address-1", "address-2", ...). The exception is thrown if no unique segment could be resolved after 100 iterations.

See [Flow documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/Routing.html#object-route-parts) for further details on "Object Route Parts".

Comment: I have some routes defined pertaining to addresses eg:
 `# Routes for Show Address
-
  name: 'Show Address'
  uriPattern: '{node}/showaddress/{--stw_shop.address}'
  defaults:
    '@package': 'TYPO3.Neos'
    '@controller': 'Frontend\Node'
    ...
    '@action':     'show'
    '--stw_shop':
      ...
      '@controller': 'Customer'
      '@action':     'showAddress'
  routeParts:
    node:
      handler:    ...
    '--stw_shop.address':
      objectType: '...\Address'
      uriPattern: '{identifier}'`

but none for actions shippingAddress or billingAddress.  Do I need them?

Comment: also in Settings.yaml I have:

  `#Shipping Address
        - package: SeeThroughWeb.Shop
          controller: Order
          action: shippingAddress
          targetNode: 1d9e6394-5e56-4e9a-85ff-72b2ea9b06ce`

   and 

       `#Billing Address
        - package: SeeThroughWeb.Shop
          controller: Order
          action: billingAddress
          targetNode: 751939c7-7aa9-422b-9e4e-3d6296a7619b`

Comment: in case it matters,  also in Settings.yaml I have:
 
  `#Shipping Address
        - package: S...hop
          controller: Order
          action: shippingAddress
          targetNode: 1d9...6ce
          targetNamespace: 'stw_shop'`

Comment: @TheNewbieQs Could you reformat your code snippets (maybe by amending them to your original question or by posting a link to a snippet if it doesn't work within comments). It's quite hard to read and it seems you omitted some important information (such as "handler: ...")